# Getting a non-const iterator in Boost's multi index container

Tags: c++, boost

Using Boost 1_33_1, I get an error implying that my iterator is a const iterator (because it wont let me deref the result from find()).

```
$ g++ bmi_iter_tst.cpp 
bmi_iter_tst.cpp: In function ‘void tst(employee_set&)’:
bmi_iter_tst.cpp:32: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘employee&’ from expression of type ‘const employee’
```

I know I am not supposed to modify any of the key values, and I don't, but I still need non-const acces sto modify other data in the container elements.

I know I have done this successfully elsewhere, I just can't see what would make this const.

The code below is derived from the original `boost::multi_index` example

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>


using boost::multi_index_container;
using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct employee
{
  int         id;
  int         tst;

  employee(int id_):id(id_), tst(0){}
};


struct id{};


typedef multi_index_container<
  employee,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_unique<
      tag<id>,  BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(employee,int,id)> >
> employee_set;


void tst(employee_set& s)
{
  employee_set::index_iterator<id>::type it = s.get<id>().find(11);
  employee& eref = *it;

  eref.tst++;
}
```

Comment: "*Using Boost 1_33_1*" Why?? This version is nearly 6 years old -- **ancient** in C++ terms.

Comment: @ildjarn It is the installed version in centos 5.5 ... soon will be moving to centos 6.0.  Centos 5.5 was the lastest and greatest (centos) just a year ago :-)

Comment: Fair enough, and also scary that CentOS doesn't update their libraries more frequently.

Comment: @ildjarn There may have been an auto update feature that I disabled, I don't like surprise updates (walk in one day and new kernel, new kernel incompatible with custom built drivers etc)

Comment: If CentOS 5.5 was new a year ago, they were still distributing a nearly 5 year old package at the time, so I don't think it's your fault. ;-]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MultiIndex docs on [random access indices](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/indices.html#rnd_indices):

> As usual in Boost.MultiIndex, elements of random access indices are
>   immutable and can only be modified through member functions replace
>   and modify. This precludes the usage of many mutating algorithms that
>   are nonetheless applicable to std::vectors.

This applies to [ordered indexes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#ord_indices) as well.

Comment: Got it ... what I don't get is the point ... If I just replace `employee` to `employee*` in the employee_set (store pointers rather than elements) it works, so the element ordering is no longer protected

Comment: Similar to how const works with const references to shared pointers. The pointers themselves are "protected" but not the data they point to. It's all about the semantics of constness.

Comment: I understand the const semantics, I am just not clear of the utility of making only const iterators as a protective step when this protection is not available when the user chooses to store ptrs.  I guess its always a question of how much rope you give/get ...

Answer (score 11):

`multi_index` doesn't know that you're not going to change members which are the key values. That's why it's only implements const_iterator.

If you want to modify non-key member you can use `modify` function. If you're going to change key value you can use `modify_key` or `replace` member functions. You can get more info [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/ord_indices.html#modifiers).

Answer (score 4):

`multi_index_container<T,...>` iterators are immutable, regardless of whether typename `T` is a class type (`U`) or pointer type (`U*`). The maintainers chose to impose this constraint to safeguard against and emphasize the fact that modifying an element directly (i.e., through an iterator) could violate the integrity-constraints of any key-based (associative) indices of the container.

**For example:** An `ordered_unique` index would be completely invalidated if direct modification of an element (through an iterator) caused the index to no longer be **ordered** or **unique**, and the `multi_index_container` itself would have no knowledge of this change/invalidation (nor would the programmer).

Here is a [verbatim explanation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/indices.html) provided by the maintainers:

> By design, index elements are immutable, i.e. iterators only grant
>   const access to them, and only through the provided updating interface
>   (replace, modify and modify_key) can the elements be modified. This
>   restriction is set up so that the **internal invariants of key-based
>   indices are not broken** (for instance, ascending order traversal in
>   ordered indices), but induces important limitations in non key-based
>   indices:

### Circumventing Const-Correctness

Of course, there are always ways around const-correctness, the most obvious way being `const_cast`... but the spirit of C++ is that a programmer **should** be allowed to do anything he or she wants, even if it's potentially dangerous. C++ language/library designers simply do the best they can to discourage such uses. And hopefully, when programmers do decide to circumvent those safeguards, it's because they have good reason and know **exactly** what they're doing.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for such an old question... I have since replaced all my boost::multi_index with boost::intrusive ... while a bit heavier on the syntax it gives me great flexibility without sacrificing performance (allowing for my object to be linked or not linked in one of the indices for example, but many more)

Comment: @nhed: I figured you had moved on to another challenge by now :) Just wanted to provide the answer for folks who arrive at this page with the same question you had. And yes... boost::intrusive is quite useful!